# How to send a Whatsapp message to a specific user using third party apps in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiapplicationdelegate, whatsapp, uiapplication

Let my app be `A` and the app user is called `A1`

I have a completely different person with his mobile mobile number - `N1`

Now I want achieve the following in my app `A` - When the user `A1` clicks on a button, `Whatsapp` is opened(if present) with a *compose message* to the number `N1`, whether or not he is in his contact list.

I am pretty sure that this is possible on Android as I my self have done it but in iOS, I am not able to find any solution. What ever solutions are out there don't achieve what I want as they open Whatsapp in general, and show me all the users out there. Please, do not redirect to the Whatsapp.com support URL as it is pretty useless.

Comment: You can't do anything more than what's here: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013 And in Whatsapp (at least iOS), you can't "compose" to an unknown number, or at least didn't find how.

Comment: Why so? I mean it's not that it is technically impossible; and if they have the functionality in Android, it should be in iOS too!!??

Comment: iOS is "more sandboxed" than Android. If the app don't allow a thing (with the URL Schemes), you won't be able to do more. Well, they may have hidden some URL acceptable, but that seems less probable, and if so, you have to find it yourself with reverse engineering.